# Kivy: GUI output window isn't showing desired outcome

Tags: python, kivy

I just started learning app programming with kivy. When I'm trying to run a very basic test programme the output window is only displaying a blank black sreen without the text ("My first App").

This is my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class My_App(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text = "My first App")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    My_App().run()
```

This is what my logfile lokks like:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Tennistrainer\.kivy\logs\kivy_23-12-20_0.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.3.3
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.6.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.2.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\Tennistrainer\PycharmProjects\kivy-thelab\pythonProject2\.venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.9.13 (tags/v3.9.13:6de2ca5, May 17 2022, 16:36:42) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\Tennistrainer\PycharmProjects\kivy-thelab\pythonProject2\.venv\Scripts\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 190 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2 (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.6.0 - Build 31.0.101.2121'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) HD Graphics Gen11'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 6
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.60 - Build 31.0.101.2121'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
```

Does anybody know how to fix that issue. Any hint is highly appreciated!
Thanx and have a good day!

Comment: your code is working perfectly on my machine, do you see any errors message in terminal?

Comment: In my professional opinion? Don't use Kivy.

Comment: @MusabbirArrafi everything is working fine, no error messages displayed. I'm wondering if it could have something to do with the installation procedere? Perhaps a component or package is missing?  The installation process of Kivy went without any complications though.

Comment: @SanguineL why is this? Are there any better technologies availabe?

Comment: It works for me as well, this is likely a problem with the environment. Could you please indicate your Kivy and Python ?

Comment: @LupaDevStudio I'm using Python 3.9.13  and Pycharme as an IDE respectively. Kivy version is 2.2.1.

Comment: @Joerg Wuljoe Ok thank you, I've got the same too. Could you please post your Kivy log in the terminal so we can check if everything is correctly loaded?

Comment: @JoergWuljoe. Absolutely. Other languages (such as C++ and Dart) are more suited for application development. I would highly recommend taking the time to learn another language, rather than spend lots of time trying to learn Kivy.

Comment: @LupaDevStudio I just uploaded the requested logfile. Hope its the right one :).

Comment: @JoergWuljoe Thank you for the log, it was the right one. The difference between your log and ours is the line "[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2" which you do not have. You can try to fix this by adding at the beginning of the file:
import os
os.environ['KIVY_TEXT'] = 'sdl2'

Comment: @LupaDevStudio thanx for your effort! Unfortunaletely this didn't fix the issue. Is there any other way to install that component?

Comment: @JoergWuljoe Ok, maybe it's a problem with the dependencies of Kivy when you installed it. Can you try to run pip install "kivy[sdl2]" ? Here is the link of the Kivy installation guide, if you want to check the installation of the dependencies : https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/installation.html
I hope this will help you to solve your problem!